# redis load module: cannot open shared object file. Permission denied

Tags: redis, travis-ci

I am successfully building the redisearch.so module on travis-ci.

After the module is built, I instruct the Redis to load it like this

```
redis-cli MODULE LOAD $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/rs/build/redisearch.so
```

which gives me the following error

```
5439:M 17 Nov 2020 09:12:55.341 # Module /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so failed to load: /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

this is what `ls -la /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so` gives me

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 travis travis 2711408 Nov 17 09:12 /home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so
```

**The question is: how do I fix this permission denied error?**

**PS**:

I have already tried to `chmod` and `chown` the `/home/travis/build/***/rs/build/redisearch.so` but with no luck.

**UPD**:
I have moved the module to /etc and it just worked

Comment: Check the ownership and permissions of all containing directories. You can do this quickly on Linux with `namei -l $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/rs/build/redisearch.so`

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thank you :)

I checked the permissions. I even chown'ed parth of the path to redis:redis. The problem is still here.

It might have to do with the fact that I use the travis-ci for the whole build process. Not sure.

Comment: If you are running `redis-server` using `systemd`, make sure it does not have `ProtectHome=true` in the service file, as it will prevent the redis server from seeing anything in the `/home` directory

Comment: @yhager this deservers to be the answer. Please post it.